# Android rotate screen and replace fragment

Tags: android, fragment

So, I have a primary activity with a fragment (FragmentA) set as default.

I have two buttons in my toolbar;
Button 1 rotates the screen and sets FragmentA's layout to landscape
Button 2 should replace FragmentA with a new FragmentB.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.split_screen) {
        currentFragment = new DualScreenFragment();
        toggleSplitScreen();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.rotate_screen) {
        currentFragment = new PrimaryPDFFragment();
        toggleScreenOrientation();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

toggleSplitScreen():

```
    private void toggleSplitScreen() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.target_pane, currentFragment);
    transaction.commit();
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

toggleScreenOrientation():

```
    private void toggleScreenOrientation() {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

However, I cant seem to handle the replacing and rotation all in one. I have to press the split screen button one to enter landscape mode and then a second time to actually replace the fragment.

Any idea as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new BlankFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Hey, tried this. It's still the same issue. I have to press the same MenuItem twice to trigger both the screen rotation and fragment replacement. Thanks anyway